# How to wait for closure to finish before returning in Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures

I have this function

```
func getSnapshot(lat: Double, lon: Double) -> UIImage? {
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.332077, -37.332077)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
        mapSnapshotOptions.region = region
        print("a")
        mapSnapshotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        mapSnapshotOptions.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        mapSnapshotOptions.showsBuildings = true
        mapSnapshotOptions.showsPointsOfInterest = true

        snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotOptions)
        print("b")
        var newImage: UIImage?
        self.snapShotter.start { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
            print("c")
            if error == nil {
                let image = snapshot!.image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                var imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 300, height: 300))
                var label = UILabel()
                label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 1, width: 30, height: 30)
                label.textAlignment = .center
                label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
                label.textColor = UIColor.gray
                label.text = "my-text"
                imageview.addSubview(label)
                imageview.image = image
                newImage = image
            } else {
                print("error")
            }

        }
        print("d")
        print(newImage)
        return newImage
    }
```

This should return an UIImage that I set inside the `snapShotter.start` closure. I wrote some print statements to check what is going on, and it prints `a b d nil c`, and what I'm looking for is to print `a b c d (image)`.

I have tried putting the closure inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async` but I keep getting the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is one of the most frequently asked questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/25203556?lq=1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning the image use closure block to pass the image back to the place you use it, like this:

```
func getSnapshot(lat: Double, lon: Double, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.332077, -37.332077)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
    mapSnapshotOptions.region = region
    print("a")
    mapSnapshotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    mapSnapshotOptions.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    mapSnapshotOptions.showsBuildings = true
    mapSnapshotOptions.showsPointsOfInterest = true

    snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotOptions)
    print("b")
    var newImage: UIImage?
    self.snapShotter.start { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
        print("c")
        if error == nil {
            let image = snapshot!.image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            var imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 300, height: 300))
            var label = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 1, width: 30, height: 30)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
            label.textColor = UIColor.gray
            label.text = "my-text"
            imageview.addSubview(label)
            imageview.image = image
            newImage = image
            print(newImage)
            completion(newImage)
        } else {
            print("error")
            completion(nil)
        }

    }
    print("d")
}
```

And the place of usage modify it to look like this:

```
getSnapshot(lat: 0, lon: 0) { image in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not down voter ... call completion in else block too ... otherwise it will always remain in memory

Comment: Thanks, I missed that bit. Not sure why people downvote right answers when the people are just trying to help others.

Comment: happens with me too bro ... dont know why ... but dont worry ... if you are learning

Comment: I did not vote, but please note that this has been asked and answered more than 100 times on SO. With 3000 rep you have the privilege to “vote to close as a duplicate” – use it!

Comment: I know that this has been asked. But I give out the answer if I know them instead of down-voting or closing so that they don't feel frustrated at the beginning of a long journey. I know how I felt when I was a beginner.